# Is throwing exceptions after initialization of an incorrect value bad style?

Tags: c++, exception, initialization

Is the following definition bad style or plain wrong? That is, is it wrong to throw *after* having intialized a value that is considered incorrect?

```
myClass::myClass(int arg) : value(arg)
   {
    if (value < 0)
       throw (myException("Negative value not allowed!"));
   }
```

It seems preferable to use the intializer-list over assigning the value in the body, and from what I understand it does not matter if I throw *after* the value has been assigned or *before*.

Comment: You should make more clear that you (IMHO, correct me if I'm wrong) don't ask if to throw at all, but if to throw after initializing the member in contrast to not initializing it in case of invalid input. The existing answers don't seem to really get that.

Comment: Some coding guidelines won't allow this. YMMV there. In that case you typically provide a static build function that returns a status of some kind along with a pointer as an output argument. The builder would check the arguments and call the constructor, which would be declared private. I'm not a fan of this, but it's a way. :)

Comment: Interesting, you learn something new every day. :)

Comment: this from the OP myClass::myClass(int arg) seems to be a constructor. As to your question you can code it that the class has some give in it.

Comment: @CraigWright: They're wrong. C++ was designed with one exception handling mechanism in mind, and that's exceptions. Not error codes. `std::vector<T>` is not going to call `int T::MaakEenNieuwObject(T&)` and guess at its return values.

Comment: @MSalters It's not incorrect. It's just poor style for most applications. However, there was a point in time ~10 years ago that exception handling, although part of the standard, was poorly implemented or in fact unimplemented in many compilers. There are lots of 10+ year old C++ code bases out there. So if you have one of these is it better to have two conventions, stick with the old, or wipe away the old and go with the new? All of that has to be traded off against the time involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `value` being >= 0 is a class invariant, then you really only have a couple of possibilities. One would be to write the ctor to accept a `unsigned` parameter, so a value <0 simply wasn't possible. The other is to throw an exception.

But yes, if the user passes a value from which you can't create a valid object, then throwing an exception is entirely acceptable (and generally the right thing to do). The constructor's responsibility is to create a valid object. If it's passed a value from which it cannot create a valid object, than an exception is generally the correct response.

As to *when* to throw the exception: at least in this case, it doesn't really matter. The exception will roll-back creation of the current object, so it will never exist anyway. It could make a difference if it was a lot faster to test the value first, rather than copying the value then destroying it if it was invalid. With things like `int` that's pretty much irrelevant. If you had, say, a large tree of some sort, and could tell whether it was valid by looking only at, say, the root node of the tree, it would probably be better to inspect that node first, and only copy the three if it was valid.

The latter is obviously an optimization, but can be a big enough and simple enough one that it may be worthwhile even without profiling (arguably, it's less optimization that just avoiding pessimization).

Comment: His question is more about the difference between throwing *after* initializing the member or not initializing it at all in case of an invalid input, not so much about if to throw at all.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative that allows the use of the initializer list and also throwing prior to initializing value if the argument isn't in the valid range:

```
inline int RequirePositive(int value)
{    
    if (value < 0) throw (myException("Negative value not allowed!"));
    return value;
}

class myClass {
    myClass(int arg) : value(RequirePositive(arg)) {}
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using an initializer list for a built in type, you are not gaining any performance advantage so why not do the assignment to the member variable after the check inside the constructor body. In your case you have a half created illegal object rather than a half created legal object. So why give the object any invalid state at all, just to be destroyed moments later.

It is okay to throw exceptions from the constructor (not so with destructor, in most cases). 
If you can not do anything meaninful with the value they pass in i.e. bump any negative value to 0 then throwing an exception seems like the thing to do, afterall you are not in a position to create a legal object.

You could use an unsigned int? 0 to 4,294,967,295. Makes it more explicit to caller that the value must be > 0.

Comment: I've changed it slightly to be more geared at his question.

Comment: "So why give the object any invalid state at all, just to be destroyed moments later."
This is what I thougt about, but then I thought it's better style to initialize all values in the intializer list, and then I went to SO. :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless that class is initialised many times in a tight loop, the loss in performance from the extra functionc all is negligible. This compared to the damages an improperly initialised class can do, it is a very small price to pay! Especially considering the "bad value" can be the result of an user input so the problems generated can be difficult to report/troubleshoot

Answer (score -1):

I would not do this. Simply use the methodology that the person using your class will understand that this is the sensible  why of using it.

Comment: Well, simply rephrasing it doesn't magically make it an answer. The question was pretty straight-forward, accompanied by a simple *example*. It wasn't about throwing exceptions from constructors or the best way to avoid negative inputs or viable alternatives to this. It was simply about throwing before initialization or after, no matter if the example is of practical value (of course an `unsigned int` is the best idea) or if it's a good idea to throw an exception at all. And saying *"forget about your question"* is a mere comment, nothing more.